# get the size of the live camera view

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way to get the size of the live camera view inside of a UIImagePickerController? (not the entire view, just the section showing the photo to be taken)

Answer (score 0):

sorry i didn't found any exact code for it BUT,
I needed same info for my app so what i did was that for camera picker's setting, i have set

```
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

so what it does it brings camera-controls in a tab bar at the bottom (use and cancel button).If it is set to NO , black colored tab bar will be shown without any buttons. So your camera preview would be of width as usual 320 and

```
height = (device's height) - tab bar's height
       = 480 - 49  //for iphone 4
width  =  320
```

it worked perfectly for me as i was also looking for this info as i neede to create preview  overlay image according to this. Works fine...